# Displaying nested json in an HTML table using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following json data as an example below. However, I could not get it to be displayed in an html table.However, it only returns 3 columns which displays "undefined". How do I properly access my json data?

```
{
  "count": 3,
  "entries": [
    {
      "affiliation": "Establishment1",
      "city": "City1",
      "code": "Code1",
      "contact": "Contact1",
      "firstname": "firstname1",
      "lastname": "lastname1",
      "middleinitial": "middleinitial1"
    },
    {
      "affiliation": "Establishment2",
      "city": "City2",
      "code": "Code2",
      "contact": "Contact2",
      "firstname": "firstname2",
      "lastname": "lastname2",
      "middleinitial": "middleinitial2"
    },
    {
      "affiliation": "Establishment3",
      "city": "City3",
      "code": "Code3",
      "contact": "Contact3",
      "firstname": "firstname3",
      "lastname": "lastname3",
      "middleinitial": "middleinitial3"
    },
  ],
  "status": "ok"
}
```

**I have tried doing this to display it in an html table:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:5000/counselorss', function (data) {
        var mdata = '';
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            mdata += '<tr>';
            mdata += '<td>'+value.lastname + '</td>';
            mdata += '<td>'+value.firstname + '</td>';
            mdata += '<td>'+value.middleinitial + '</td>';
            mdata += '<td>'+value.contact + '</td>';
            mdata += '<td>'+value.affiliation + '</td>';
            mdata += '<td>'+value.city + '</td>';
            mdata += '<td>'+value.code + '</td>';
            mdata += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#counselorstable').append(counselor_data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you ever tried to do debug the `data`  response ? Something like `console.log(data)`.

Comment: Looks like you want `$.each(data.entries, ...)` here, not `$.each(data, ...)`.

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes! thank you. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:5000/counselorss', function (data) {
        var mdata = '';
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $.each(data['entries'], function (key, value) {
            mdata += '<tr>';
            mdata += '<td>'+value.lastname + '</td>';
            mdata += '<td>'+value.firstname + '</td>';
            mdata += '<td>'+value.middleinitial + '</td>';
            mdata += '<td>'+value.contact + '</td>';
            mdata += '<td>'+value.affiliation + '</td>';
            mdata += '<td>'+value.city + '</td>';
            mdata += '<td>'+value.code + '</td>';
            mdata += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#counselorstable').append(counselor_data);
    }); 
});
```